# How do I calculate the following radius of convergence?

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

**Original equation:**

[image]

To determine de radius of convergence. I use R = 1/L. Where R is the radius and L is the limit.

The answer is supposed to be limit L = 0.

So R = 1/0 = ∞

So this limit is supposed to be 0 :

[image: Formula]

To calculate the limit I tried using:

[image]

Is there an easier/other way to calculate this limit? Because I doesn't seem to lead anywhere...

Comment: $$\frac{n!(2n)!}{(4n)!} = \frac{1}{\binom{4n}{2n}\binom{2n}{n}n!}$$

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks for commenting.I see where that's going. But I do not see how you got to that answer. Did you divide both the nom. and denom. by n!(2n)!  ?

Comment: Effectively, that's what I did.